# No actualizar un paquete de bundle de symfony 5.4

Tags: php, composer, symfony5

Existe alguna de que cuando se ejecute un composer install o update en symfony , se un paquete poseo un paquete de bundle que modifique y cuando instalo nuevas dependencias se pierden dichos cambios en el paquete que modifique

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma de editar los paquetes de la carpeta ***vendor*** por medio de parches (***patches***)

Instalar vendor-patches:

`composer require symplify/vendor-patches --dev`

1. Cree una copia del archivo ***/vendor*** que desee cambiar con el sufijo ****.old***

Por ejemplo, si el archivo a editar es *InjectExtension.php*:

```
vendor/nette/di/src/DI/Extensions/InjectExtension.php
# haz una copia con el sufijo .old
vendor/nette/di/src/DI/Extensions/InjectExtension.php.old
```

2. Abra el archivo original y cambie las líneas que necesita:

Solo se carga el archivo `*.php`, no el `*.php.old`. De esta manera, puede **estar seguro de que el nuevo código** funciona antes de generar parches.

3. Ejecute el comando 'generate' ️

```bash
vendor/bin/vendor-patches generate
```

Esta herramienta generará **archivos de parches para todos los archivos creados de esta manera** en el directorio `/patches`:

```bash
/patches/nette-di-di-extensions-injectextension.php.patch
```

La ruta del parche se basa en la ruta del archivo original, por lo que **el nombre del parche siempre es único**.

Ahora todo lo que necesita hacer es ejecutar:

```bash
composer install
```

Mas información en:
https://github.com/symplify/vendor-patches